# Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000

Tags: c

I tried this program many times, but I can't write answer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long unsigned int i,sum=0;
    clrscr();
    for(i=0;i<=1000;i++)
    {
        if((i%5==0)||(i%3==0))
        {
            sum=sum+1;
        }
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I want an answer like this:
If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if((i%5==0)||(i%3==0))
        {
            sum=sum+1;
        }
```

should be

```
if((i%5==0)||(i%3==0))
        {
            sum=sum+i;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
  sum=sum+1;
```

to

```
sum=sum+i;
```

Answer (score 1):

You've hard-coded `1` into your loop, instead of `i`. It should be (added white space for clarity - it's free):

```
if ((i % 5 == 0) || (i % 3 == 0))
    {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
if ((i % 5 == 0) || (i % 3 == 0))
    {
        sum += i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Very basic error, you must take the loop value i instead of 1 after your if condition

```
sum = sum + 1
```

must be

```
sum = sum + i
```

And if you don't want to include the thousand, your loop must be

```
for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
```